# Court, Courtyard and Yard

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

What do you normally call such a place which is belonged to a particular building:

[image][image][image]

> **Court:** 
>   -  an area or a short road that is not covered by a roof and is mostly or completely surrounded by buildings.
>
> **Courtyard:** 
>   - an area of flat ground outside that is partly or completely surrounded by the walls of a building.
>
> **Yard:** 
>   - an area of land next to a building that usually has a hard surface and that is used for a special purpose.

While according to all these definitions, they all can be alludes to these pictures, I have raised this question here to find out the nuance between these words.

Comment: There are regional differences in what is considered a *yard*, *garden*, *courtyard*, and *[various other terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156071/)*; what is your locale?

Comment: Personally, I would call it a **patio**. In some cases similar to these, however, **terrace**, **garden**, or **lawn** can also be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my locale (Australia, similar to British English):

A yard is part of the building it is adjacent to (and shares the same owner), for example: backyard.

A court (as per your provided definition) is an area surrounded by buildings. It can be privately owned or a part of public property (such as a park or road).

Thus a courtyard is specifically a court that is privately owned.